# send command to emacs daemon from shell

Tags: shell, emacs, org-mode

Emacs command `org-html-convert-region-to-html` can convert org mode to html file and I have a project which is a Java program where I need handle the org mode file and convert it to html.
I want use system call to interactive with emacs daemon, which similar as execute shell command at terminal, and I could get the response from shell output stream to my program.
Can I start a emacs daemon and send the `org-html-convert-region-to-html` command to it which response a output html format stream in shell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs can be set-up to run a [server](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html). Then you could run [`emacsclient`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Invoking-emacsclient.html) commands (perhaps with the `-e` option, to evaluate expressions)

Emacs could also be [started specially](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Invocation.html#Emacs-Invocation) to run some Elisp commands (and could be started without opening any windows).

<sup>(however, I don't think your design is a good one. You could consider [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) `org` files in Java instead, and that is probably more suitable in your case)</sup>

Comment: emacsclient open a new window and I don't need a interactive environment.  How can I  send `org-html-convert-region-to-html` command to emacs server in shell and get the result?

Comment: RTFM. You might use `emacsclient -e`, but I believe your overall approach is wrong.

Comment: It's just a small usage and I think emacs will give me best html parsing.Thanks

Comment: You don't parse HTML. If you did, you'll use a very different tool (perhaps a browser).

Comment: Sorry, It should be org mode parsing.

Comment: Haha, maybe you have familiar with it enough. I scared by it's [document](https://orgmode.org/manual/).